# Unity, C++, opening a Unity folder out of a QT-application

Tags: unity, qt, c++

I wrote an QT-application, which shows a "QTreeWidget" of a certain directory
and its sub-directories.
Now I would like to make unity open a folder e.g. `/home/Username/`,
by clicking one of the applications "QTreeWidgetItems".

Unfortunately i don't know how the communication between Unity and the Qt-app works.
Can somebody tell me how that could be done ?

Thank you,
DocCruiser

Comment: There's no such thing as a Unity folder. Can you update your answer to explain exactly what you want to happen? I don't understand what you mean by making Unity open a folder.

Comment: I mean the usual folder from the filemanager.

Answer (score 1):

The default manager is Ubuntu is nautilus. You can open a folder with nautilus with this command

```
nautilus /path/to/folder
```

But this will only work when nautilus is installed (i.e. in gnome or plain Ubuntu). You can also use this command:

```
xdg-open /path/to/folder
```

This should open the folder with the default file-manager of the user. It will work the same way that the above command for plain Ubuntu, but will open Konkeror in Kubuntu or Thunar in Xubuntu.

Comment: Thank you Javier. I solved the problem allready yesterday after reading an article about nautilus. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager. Thank you for your help.